# Mocha / Chai - Timeout, ensuring promise resolves

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

There's several thousand questions on this and I think I've read all of them but I still don't understand why the following doesn't work.

Locally this code executes without an issue.  When run on TravisCI - it fails with the ensure done() is being called error.

```
it('Function oLab.GetObjects & oLab.Deploy', (done) => {
    var l = new oLab('1')
    l.getObjects().then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        expect(data.length).to.above(0);
        //There is a bunch of other code in here commented out since this alone doesn't work.  
    })
    .then(() => done(), done)
    .catch(function (err) {     }); // Not executed
});
```

I know the getObjects function is failing:

```
this.getObjects = function () {
    console.log("oLab getObjects function");
    return getResources(this.id);
}
```

which calls getResources:

```
function getResources(labID){
    return db.any('select * from lab_resources where lab_id = ' + labID).then(function(data){
        var resources = [];
        //Modifies the resources and returns the list.  Logging this displays the correct data.  
        return resources;
    })
    .catch(function (err) {     }); // Not executed
```

}

Questions:

1. I read this [blog](https://wietse.loves.engineering/testing-promises-with-mocha-90df8b7d2e35) and based off of it added (done) to my functions as I think I return a promise.  Do I return a promise if it is nested?  IE I call getObjects followed by getResources.  getResources returns a DB query but within that - there is a value returned.  Does that mean I'm returning a promise or the value to the calling function?  I thought it would return the promise as the promise wouldn't be executed immediately.
2. Within getObjects, I'm trying to set a property of oLab.  Should I set that property within the getObjects function or should I return that to my calling method and then alter the property of oLab?

Comment: Having other people read this should be a good reminded why you should have good descriptive names for tests. I can't tell what you testing here with "Function oLab.GetObjects & oLab.Deploy". Using `catch` and the second callback to `then` is probably a mistake because you will intercept the error generated by a failing test.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I have logging in both catch statements and neither of them log thus I didn't think they were executing and why I left them off.  I wrote a significantly more complicated test that I've stripped down to this as it was still failing the basic test in TravisCI.  If I caught - and logged - the error on the inner function, why is it a bad idea to nest catch statements?

Comment: You are using both callbacks in `then` with `then(done, done)` The second call back is for errors. Unless you throw in the second call back `catch()` will never happen. It's much easier with mocha to leave `done` out of it and just return the promise.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I can understand the rationale for returning the promise however when return l.getObjects() - it timesout which is why I turned to done.  I know l.getObjects returns a promise as if I set l.getObjects equal to a variable and log it, it shows promise.  I started with returning the promises directly then turned to done() as I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: You need to make sure you remove `done` from `it('Function oLab.GetObjects & oLab.Deploy', (done) `. That's how it knows to look for a promise.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I hate to be a pain but it still fails to resolve.  I effectively changed it to return l.getObjects().then(function..).  It never appears to execute the .then portion?  Locally this all works - its only on Travis that it fails.  It fails to execute based on the timeout still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Travis CI wasn't able to access the Database I was requesting thus it was failing on the DB connection setup.